# Volume of a truncated concave solid (only surface mesh data is known)

Tags: analytic-geometry, matlab, volume

I will start with an example.

This is the image of the mesh of a solid of revolution of a combination of a triangle and a parabola
[image: solid of revolution of a combination of a triangle and a parabola]

It consists of only the surface mesh(quadrilaterals and triangles). I also know the average mesh size. In the above image, the height is 100 units and the average mesh size is 2 units.
A plane cuts the solid into 2 parts. The plane can be oriented in any way but can only cut the solid into 2 parts (not necessarily equal).

What I need to compute is a large set of points on the cutting plane. I can then feed the points on the surface and points (nodes of the mesh) on the required side of the normal to the plane into alphaShape in MATLAB and get the volume.

The mesh is an approximation to the actual surface of the solid, I'm not interested in the exact value, just a very good approximation of the volume.

Here is my approach for convex bodies.

Project all points whose normal distances to the cutting plane are less than the average mesh size.
Then considering only the points projected on the surface, find the boundary points using boundary function in MATLAB. Populate the region inside the boundary with more points.

I get within 80-95% of the actual value (when tested for known shapes) but there is room for improvement. For example, for a cone with a cutting plane halfway from its height and parallel to the base, It would be better if I can somehow take the average boundary of the points projected from the top and bottom of the plane for better results.

Is there a better way. Is there a more general way that I can also use for concave shapes and oblique cutting planes?

I think that if I can get the points on the edges of each element cut by the plane, then I can get a very good approximation but I don't know any way for doing that.

It would be very helpful if someone points me in the right direction.

What I can't do: I cannot change the mesh data.

Comment: I think I have catched what you are mainly after. A first level of improvement looks possible: you select points that are at a distance less that the average mesh size, but among them, do you sort out those that are below from those that are above the sectioning plane ? This possible if the equation of the sectioning plane is $ax+by+cz-d=0$ and if a point has coordinates $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, by knowing the sign of  $ax_0+by_0+cz_0-d$...

Comment: Yes, I do sort out the points above and below the sectioning plane, just like you mentioned, before projecting the points onto the plane. So I have 2 polygons on the plane. But I want an average of the 2 polygons if that makes sense.

Comment: 1) If you happen to know for example that "upper point" $U(x_u,y_u,z_u)$ is connected to "lower point"  $(x_l,y_l,z_l)$ then the weighted average with the weight ratio $|ax_l+by_l+cz_l-d|$ vs. $|ax_u+by_u+cz_u-d|$ belongs exactly to the cutting plane 2) Have you heard about the CRUST algorithm (?